# Regex stylesheet out of string

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to use regex to get the stylesheets inside it, I use this regex now: `/(<link .*href=["'])/gi`

but this returns me all `<link` but I want to filter on link and `rel="stylesheet"`

could someone help me out on this regex?

Comment: Use a parser - [H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: *inside it* inside what?

Comment: What is the input you are passing? Is it a string?

Answer (score 2):

> but this returns me all

Why not use the built-in `querySelectorAll`

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll("link[rel='stylesheet']");
console.log(links.length);
```

`links` is the list of link `Element`s.

**Demo**

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll("link[rel='stylesheet']");
console.log(links.length);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="abc.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="abc2.css"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have got you correctly then you are trying to get all `links` with `rel="stylesheet"` attribute. To do so you can use following `regex`

`/<link .*rel="stylesheet".*\/>/gi`

For demonstrations have a look [here](https://regexr.com/3mfid).